# unable to insert values to the classAttributeAssignment in impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

```
$classificationSystem=hpeClassification 
$classificationCatalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$classificationSystem]),version[default='1.0'])[unique=true,default=$classificationSystem:1.0] 
$classificationSystemVersion=systemVersion(catalog(id[default=$classificationSystem]),version[default='1.0'])[unique=true,default=$classificationSystem:1.0]
$code=/facet/Category
$class=classificationClass($code,$classificationCatalogVersion)[unique=true]
$attribute=classificationAttribute(code,$classificationSystemVersion)[unique=true]
$unit=unit(code,$classificationSystemVersion)

INSERT_UPDATE ClassAttributeAssignment;$class;$attribute;multiValued[default=false];range[default=false];attributeType(code[default=string]);localized[default=true];$unit;attributeValues(code,$classificationSystemVersion);
```

Comment: What is the error? Could be please be more precise?

Comment: unable to insert values into the below impex format , how to insert values to the parameters inside paranthesis? classificationAttribute(code,$classificationSystemVersion)[unique=true]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of macro for code(i.e $code).I modified the impex and bellow version should work(However it will not insert nothing in DB):

```
$classificationSystem=hpeClassification    
$classificationCatalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$classificationSystem]),version[default='1.0'])[unique=true,default=$classificationSystem:1.0] 
$classificationSystemVersion=systemVersion(catalog(id[default=$classificationSystem]),version[default='1.0'])[unique=true,default=$classificationSystem:1.0]
$class=classificationClass(code,$classificationCatalogVersion)[unique=true]
$attribute=classificationAttribute(code,$classificationSystemVersion)[unique=true]
$unit=unit(code,$classificationSystemVersion)

INSERT_UPDATE ClassAttributeAssignment;$class;$attribute;multiValued[default=false];range[default=false];attributeType(code[default=string]);localized[default=true];$unit;attributeValues(code,$classificationSystemVersion);
```

An example of inserting an instance in DB would be:

```
$classificationSystem=hpeClassification
$classificationCatalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$classificationSystem]),version[default='1.0'])[unique=true,default=$classificationSystem:1.0]
$classificationSystemVersion=systemVersion(catalog(id[default=$classificationSystem]),version[default='1.0'])[unique=true,default=$classificationSystem:1.0]
$class=classificationClass(code,$classificationCatalogVersion)[unique=true]
$attribute=classificationAttribute(code,$classificationSystemVersion)[unique=true]
$unit=unit(code,$classificationSystemVersion)

INSERT_UPDATE ClassAttributeAssignment;$class;$attribute;multiValued[default=false];range[default=false];attributeType(code[default=string]);localized[default=true];$unit;attributeValues(code,$classificationSystemVersion);
;accessoryclassification;bands
```

Where "accessoryclassification" is the code of an already existing(in DB) Classification Class and "bands" is the code of already existing  classification attribute

Comment: thank u for your response, But have a question i.e how can we provide values to the existing classification attribute through impex and how can we assign it to classification. I am not getting that.can u please explain